# Efficient way to store FilePath

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently I have a table with the following format/Desc:

```
ColumnName  ColID   PK  IndexPos    Null    DataType
ID          1                   1   N       VARCHAR2 (1 Byte)
FILEPATH    2                       N       VARCHAR2 (127 Byte)
```

As you can see the length of ID Column is only 1 Byte we can store only 36 different file paths. I have more than 35 different file paths that has to be stored and retrieved. I know increasing the length of ID solves the issue but I want to also know/suggestion that is there any Efficient way to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can store 256 values in one byte. Where are you getting 35 from? What do you mean by 'efficient' here; and if the ID is synthetic (as it appears to be) why have you chosen that data type rather than, say, a number?

Comment: @AlexPoole [A-Z & 0-9 = 36], How is it 256?
Or may be I'm describing it wrong. one file path will have a different/unique ID which will help in retrieving the data. EX: Select Filepath from XXX table where ID = 'A';. Thus then the program will look into that path and pick that file.

Comment: Those are alphanumeric characters; they are a small subset of the byte values you can use. The [128 ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) all fit in one byte (with one bit to spare!). Even if you're restricted to printable characters (which you haven't mentioned) that's many more than 36; ASCII values 0x20 to to 0x7e are all printable... If you are restricted you need more bytes, or a different data type. You still haven't said what 'efficient' means to you.

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry my bad. It's because of my low level of knowledge I haven't mentioned much. Efficient means should I increase the length or go with upper & lower case (Which I came to know just now) etc, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion that you can store only 35 different values in the table is incorrect, because `varchar2` characters are not limited to letters and digits (even if they were you'd have 26 letters + 10 digits + 1 empty string = 37, not 35 possibilities).

If you need to store few more paths, say, 40 or 50, you could make your keys mixed case, so `'a'` and `'A'` would reference different paths. This would instantly give you 26 extra possibilities.

Expanding past the limit of 63 is a little harder, because you need to bring special characters into the mix. However, the theoretical maximum for a single character is 256 plus one combination for an empty string.

Comment: Wow :) great explanation. So, without even doing anything I can take 256 plus one combination for an empty string. Thanks for the info, I have to re-think about it. But, do you think like just increasing the length would be a good approach rather than using special characters?

Comment: @Developer I'd go for a two-character fixed-length code, because once you get into case-sensitivity and non-printable characters, running and interpreting queries against your DB manually becomes harder.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for your suggestion/help.